# Cannot assign value of type 'Int!' to type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift

```
    operation = (sender as AnyObject).tag
```

i'm working on a calculator app, while in the bottom i'm trying to send my operations to the sender.tag but I get the error

> Cannot assign value of type 'Int!' to type 'String'

```
This error also generates more errors in the bottom like
```

> "override' can only be specified on class members"
>
> "'super' cannot be used outside of class members"
>
> "'override' can only be specified on class members"
>
> "'super' cannot be used outside of class members"

and are the errors generated from these lines?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Check the balance of the braces (`{}`). One is missing or on the wrong level. And `sender as AnyObject` is awful. Declare the type of  `sender` in the `IBAction` as the real type (most likely `UIButton`)

Comment: Please edit the question with your full class with proper formatting please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. Your `operation` variable is a `String`. You are trying to assign an incompatible type `Int` to it.

```
let number = (sender as AnyObject).tag
operation = String(number)
```

OR

```
operation = "\(number)"
```

You class should look something like this.

```
class YourClass: UIViewController {
    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```